# How to find and replace the string with iterated values (multi lines) in shell script

Tags: linux, sed

this is my shell  script to replace the string

> OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"

with multi line string values

> OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:1234"
>   OPTIONS_1235="-p ${PIDFILE_1235} -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:1235"
>   OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:1236"

based  on  my input port number , that many OPTIONS should be created.

```
#!/bin/bash    
NS_HOSTNAME= localhost
namingService_ports = 1234,1235,1236
IFS=','
read -r -a portArray <<< "$namingService_ports"

for port in ${portArray[@]}; do
        sed '0,/\PTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"/ s//\OPTIONS_'"$port"'="-p ${PIDFILE_'"$port"'} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/'"$NS_HOSTNAME"':'"$port"'"\n  /' "/etc/init.d/tao" > "tao_ns1"
done
```

can some suggest me  how sed command will take the multi line with  for  loop  and  move to the file "tao_ns1"

Comment: Please pay more attention to the tags you put on questions. Why did you have "java" there for example?!

Comment: by mistake i added

Comment: You asked a similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790904/how-to-replace-the-string-in-exec-file-with-multi-line-in-optimized-manner

Comment: Thats, small  difference is there , what is happening here is like ,  while iterating first iterated value only its taking , i'm looking for complete iterated data should be available in  end file

Comment: @PravinKmr: refer my update below and don't forget to upvote/accept the answer once it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 3 issues with your script.

1. The assignment `namingService_ports = 1234,1235,1236` is incorrect in `bash` and it should be without spaces, i.e. `namingService_ports="1234,1235,1236"`
2. There is a typographical error in first `sed` option for `OPTIONS` i.e. `sed '0,/\PTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"` should have been `sed '0,/\OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"`
3. And while writing to a file `"tao_ns1"` you are using the `>` operator which basically over-writes the file every-time you run it. It should have been the `>>` append operator, which appends the new line to the file for every iteration of the loop.

Also http://www.shellcheck.net/, that you have carriage return characters in your script, run `tr` command on it before proceeding next.

```
tr -d '\r' < current_script.sh > new_script.sh
```

With the above fixes made.

```
#!/bin/bash

NS_HOSTNAME="localhost"
namingService_ports="1234,1235,1236"
IFS=','
read -r -a portArray <<< "$namingService_ports"

for port in ${portArray[@]}; do
        sed '0,/\OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE}"/ s//\OPTIONS_'"$port"'="-p ${PIDFILE_'"$port"'} -ORBEndpoint iiop:\/\/'"$NS_HOSTNAME"':'"$port"'"\n  /' "/etc/init.d/tao" >> "tao_ns1"
done
```

should work fine.

Comment: Here /etc/init.d/tao file i have OPTIONS="-p ${PIDFILE} and i want to replace it with multi lines based on portArray containing port numbers count and  replace original one

Comment: output should be OPTIONS_1234="-p ${PIDFILE_1234} -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:1234"                                                                   OPTIONS_1235="-p ${PIDFILE_1235} -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:1235"                                                                 OPTIONS_1236="-p ${PIDFILE_1236} -ORBEndpoint  iiop://localhost:1236"

Comment: but curretly it is taking as /etc/init.d/tao complete file multiple time append in same file  with OPTIONS

Comment: @PravinKmr: don't copy paste code block in comments. What is your requirement now? Just replacing the original file `"/etc/init.d/tao"` with `"tao_ns1"` ?

Comment: @PravinKmr: My current script creates a new file `"tao_ns1"` with the expanded options? You want to replace that with the file under `init.d`?

Comment: can you refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790904/how-to-replace-the-string-in-exec-file-with-multi-line-in-optimized-manner/40792681#40792681 , there i explained overall requirement

Comment: Your requirements are not clear at all, both here and there. Just specify clearly what is that you have and what you need.

Comment: there i mentioned like after installation ,showing the default  created file and  expected output file from that  at below  , Apart from  we can hardcode NS_PORTS AND Hostname , those are i'm getting  from  system env

Comment: @PravinKmr: Have no idea what you are trying to explain.

Comment: ok  i'll  close these and open fresh one with  my proper query

Answer (score 0):

Two examples that I hope helps to reach want you want to ...

Changing a string and redirect the result to a new file, replacing AAA to BBB:

```
echo "xxxAAAxxx" | sed  "s/AAA/BBB/i" > out.ini
```

Same logic (replacing BBBto CCC), but at this time replace some string inside an existing file

```
sed  -i "s/BBB/CCC/i" out.ini
```